# Multiple or duplicate cursors

Tags: macos, bug, cursor

I'm seeing a problem where I have multiple mouse cursors on certain parts of my screen or screen configurations. I've searched bug reports and haven't seen any mention of something similar, so I'm wondering if anyone has seen this problem before.

I've tried:

- Restating the computer
- Updating the OS

I'm hesitant to wipe and re-install everything... but that's my next step unless I can solve this annoying bug.

*When I take a screenshot, the second cursor disappears, so please excuse the phone photos*.

**Pointer and I-bar on text input:**

[image]

**Pointer and drag hand when editing the previous photo:**

[image]

**Second cursor on a monitor that is rotated 90° CC (vertical):**

[image]

**Computer Information:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried resetting your SMC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a tip from a co-worker to reset my [SMC](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/reset-macs-smc-pram/) (which I hadn't tried yet), and that solved the problem.

To reset the SMC, hold `Shift`, `Control`, and `Option` while the computer is plugged in. It restarted my machine and the problem is now resolved.